# stellar docker and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: horizon, docker

I am running a stellar docker using this command:

```
sudo docker run -d --rm -it -p "7777:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
```

which will bind the horizon (port 8000) to my host port 7777.
I also configure my ubuntu server to proxy to the port 7777 and is using https.
But the response from the horizon is http. Is there any configuration so the docker can receive https?
Here are the response from horizon:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "account": {
      "href": "http://www.horizon.test.net/accounts/{account_id}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "account_transactions": {
      "href": "http://www.horizon.test.net/accounts/{account_id}/transactions{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "assets": {
      "href": "http://www.horizon.test.net/assets{?asset_code,asset_issuer,cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup SSL offloading on the nginx server. Actually, it's one of the most common nginx use-cases. Browser interacts with your nginx server via HTTPS protocol, and then requests get proxied to the Horizon docker instance via HTTP.

Check [the detailed guide for Let'sEncrypt with nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) by DigitalOcean.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i have done that too. i think the issue is because the connection that get proxied to horizon is http, so the response is in http?

Comment: Make sure your proxy sends valid `X-Forwarded-Proto` header: https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/httpx/base_url.go#L19